# Morphing from text to shape

Tags: modeling, animation, text-object

[image]I am trying to morph text into shape. Is there a convenient way to do this in Blender? For example, how would I morph the text "CH3" into a sphere? Please help if you know how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: I guess it really depends how your text object looks like, etc... maybe show a video, some pictures, or even a drawing of what you want?

Comment: Please see added image. I am trying to morph the CH3 into a yellow sphere. This is one example but I'd like to eventually morph between the other spheres and text as well.

Comment: I guess you want to replace the sphere from the text , you can do that probably by linking their object data  , click both of them and do CTRL L and select object data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can use shrinkwrap modifier and some transparency animation to do that:

[image]

We can keep the text as it is: just give it a little extrusion (text property panel), and convert it to mesh (menu *"object/convert to"*) as we'll need a vertex group.

Then add a support sphere that is around the text. This sphere will not be rendered and is just here to be projected on.

Add a vertex group to the text and add it this modifiers:

[image]

- Vertex weight proximity onto the geometry of the support sphere and using the vertex group. We'll animate *"global influence"* parameter from 0 to 1, so that the text vertex group progressively go to 1.
- Subdivsion surface which helps to get rid of artifacts
- Shrinkwrap to the support sphere, using the same vertex group and with the parameter shown above

The text shader is directly a color to get rid of normal issues (see blend file).

Now use a second sphere, which will be visible at the end, as its alpha/transparency is animated.

This sphere is itself projected on the text using another shrinkwrap modifier, with the following parameters:

[image]

This sphere is fully shaded (see blend file) and adds the color transition.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I made an attempt following your directions but I must have missed something because even though the animation works, it is not nearly as nice as the one you made. I have the blend file but I don't know how to upload it here..

Comment: You can use this link to upload a file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you. I uploaded my blend file here. I am using the cycles engine in Blender 2.9.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6qWPS1GB" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6qWPS1GB/)

Comment: Here is your file with some modifications (commented in the viewport). [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=J4KNan5N" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/J4KNan5N/) You'll have to tune the transparency effect to make it ok with Cycles (used Eevee in the answer).

Comment: Got it to work this time. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed a bounding box associated with the support sphere in your files when I switch to object mode. I was curious about where that is coming from. Thank you.

Comment: It is an option in the object property panel (viewport visibility)... that allow to see things better for elements that are not rendered (for instance).

Comment: I see. Got it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a basic solution and a bit more complete one, using both the ***Cast*** modifier:

[image]

- Create your text, once converted in mesh, press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to simplify it and use a grid and the *Knife Project* tool to subdivide it:

[image]

- Put its origin at its geometry, create an empty somewhere behind, give it a *Cast* modifier with the empty as *Object*, play with the factor:

[image]

[image]

- Create a sphere that has the same radius as the spherical text. Keyframe the *Cast* factor and the material of the text and of the sphere in order to make them disappear and appear. If you use Eevee, you need to choose *Alpha Mode > Alpha Blend* in the *Settings* of the material:

[image]

You can improve if you use shapekeys:

[image]

- Create your letters, create 2 shapekeys for the object, keep the second selected, select your letters and extrude them, select the rims:

[image]

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to inflate:

[image]

- Delete the extrusion to have a flat topology:

[image]

- This time you will animate both the shapekeys (from the shapekey 1 to 2), the *Cast* modifier and the material to get the animation, keep the sphere as in the first method to make the transition to a complete sphere.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and two separate approaches. As the first one seemed simpler I tried that first. I got the text to work with the cast modifier but I can't seem to get the sphere animation right. I have the blend file but I am not sure how I can attach it here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't go into details, to make the sphere appear you need to create a material which is a mix (with Mix Shader) between a Diffuse and a Transparent node, then just animate the factor of the Mix Shader so that it begins 100% transparent and ends up 100% colorful

Comment: I actually did use the mix shader and  keyframed the factor values. I'll check again to see if I missed something while doing that. In any case, the information you provided is "super" helpful in teaching stereochemistry to my students. Much appreciated.