# Is there a way to morph between two different shapes made with shader nodes

Tags: node-editor, procedural, mathematics

I've made a couple of simple shapes (Just a circle and a star) and I wanted to be able to have a slider that at 0 would be one shape and at 1 be the other. Right now I'm using a value which is rounded then used as a factor for a mixRGB node with the two values being the shapes, so when I move the slider the shape snaps to the other, but I want it to be able to smoothly transition to the other. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I would use the Shrinkwrap Modifier and Shapekeys for that. Searching/googling for "shapekeys" and "morphing" should yield multiple usable results. [Here is one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195240/morphing-from-text-to-shape) for example.

Comment: Ehm, I seem to have misunderstood your question. I'm not sure at all you can use shapekeys for that, so never mind. (sorry)

Comment: This depends on how you are producing your star - can you update your question to include an image of your material nodes?

Comment: Multiply the displacement of shape A by fac and the displacement of shape B by (1 - fac) and add the two. You can also use a map range node or a RGB curves if you want non-linear interpolation. Please share your node tree :) (At least the part right before the displacement output)